# ChartJs line chart repaint glitch while hovering over

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, chart.js

I have the following code leveraging the ChartJS library.

```
/*assume the tags in the right place */

<canvas id="graph1" width="300" height="300"></canvas>

var ctx = $("#graph1").get(0).getContext("2d");
var myChart = new Chart(ctx).Line(graph1Generator("day"));
```

... everything works fine, but after adding the following event handler to clear and repaint the same chart with different data, a glitch occurs.

```
weekButton.addEventListener("click", function(){
    ctx.clearRect (0, 0, 300, 300);
    ctx.canvas.width = 300;
    ctx.canvas.height = 300;
    myChart = new Chart(ctx).Line(graph1Generator("week"));
```

This code does successfully redraw the chart with the new data, but when I hover over it, it does some very strange "flashbacks" to the old chart that it was supposed to clear. This makes me believe that it didn't clear the old one.

Comment: I think it'll work if you just re-use the old chart object instead of creating a new one in the event handler. You can also call `myChart.destroy();` right before you create a new one, as an alternative.

Comment: How would I reuse the old chart object with new data? While the charts are the same, they have different types of data. Also, `myChar.destroy();` seems to be duplicating my chart size after every event. Why is that happening?

Comment: I think just `myChart.Line(graph1generator("week"));` (or whatever you need to do for the new data).  And instead of clearing the canvas with your code, let Chart do it: `myChart.clear();`. (That might work better than `.destroy()`; I'm not sure.)

Comment: While myChart.clear() doesn't duplicate the size, it still doesn't solve the glitch. Also, when change the object like `myChart.Line(graph1generator("week"));`, I get a `ReferenceError: Can't find variable: graph1generator `. That is strange since its a function defined 1 scope above (global scope).

Comment: Without seeing more code it's hard to know what's going on. Have you tried duplicating the issue in jsfiddle or CodePen or something?

Comment: Well, here is the entire code http://jsfiddle.net/nirchernia/oh8mmLpg/ , it doesnt really seem to replicate even with the Chart.min.js library. It could be because of bootsrap?

Comment: The `graph1generator()` error is just a typo (should be "Generator").

Comment: Good point. But now I get `[Error] TypeError: undefined is not a function (evaluating 'myChart.Line(graph1Generator("week"))')`

Comment: Yes - sorry I had to drop off to go to a meeting :) I think I can fix the fiddle to show you what I'm doing ... hang on a bit

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Here is an update to your fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/h42tv3xv/) The primary change (other than fixing the function name typo) is to add

```
myChart.destroy();
```

before lines like

```
myChart = new Chart(ctx).Line(...);
```

The `.destroy()` method gets rid of the event handler registrations etc, so you shouldn't see those weird "ghost charts" when you mouse over the graphics.

Comment: Your jsfiddle works but has a weird side effect. On the fiddle, the other canvas's start to exponetially increase in size after every event handler is run. On my page (testing in safari), the line chart only seems to get exponentially bigger. I am running your exact code, is there a way for this not to happen?

Comment: @ApathyBear I don't see anything getting bigger when I run it. You can add `.destroy()` calls for the other charts too, but that doesn't make much difference when I try it.

Comment: @ApathyBear I've tried Firefox and Chrome, and in neither case to the pie and doughnut charts ever change size.

Comment: Thanks. It must be something unique to me. I really appreciate all the help. I thought I was crazy!

Comment: for reference, this is what I was seeing after enough clicks. https://app.box.com/s/5vy4nhl37eyyprnjems0hkgc5mj96n0h, no idea why. Weird.

Comment: @ApathyBear that's pretty weird; I've never experienced Chart.js changing the size of a `<canvas>` at all.

Comment: I had the same issue as @ApathyBear. Setting the 'responsive' option to true fixed it.

Comment: I've only recently started using an up-to-date version of Chart, so now I know what people are talking about :).  When I wrote those previous comments a couple years ago, I was (for various reasons) stuck on a fairly old version of the library, for which I had written my own resizing code.