# Side effects from Chartjs for only *some* clients

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, chart.js

I was working on a couple of Chart.js charts and have found some strange behavior.

In this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/h42tv3xv/ people have been getting a variety of side effects when pressing the buttons "Day", "Week", or "Month".

**What it should do:**
Simply refresh the chart with potentially new information displayed(the pie and doughnut actually don't have anything new)

**What it should not do:**
As a side effect for *some*, it is growing the size of the `<canvas>` on each click. It does it for me. But it doesn't do it for a lot of other people accessing this fiddle. Here is a screen shot:

[image]

Why is it doing this for some people and not others? How can I remedy this problem? If you are curious, I initially asked a question about something else about these charts, but this could be somewhat [related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30058382/chartjs-line-chart-repaint-glitch-while-hovering-over/30061916?noredirect=1#comment48240331_30061916).

Any clue what could be causing this in my browser and other browsers/computers?

**Edit, I realize the fiddle is large, so this is what I am doing essentially:**

```
// Assign and Create all canvas contexts 
    var ctx = $("#graph1").get(0).getContext("2d");
    var ctx2 =  $("#graph2").get(0).getContext("2d");
    var ctx3 =  $("#graph3").get(0).getContext("2d");

// Instantiate new charts and pass in generated data
    var myChart = new Chart(ctx).Line(graph1Generator("day"));
    var myDoughnutChart = new Chart(ctx2).Doughnut(graph2Generator("day"));
    var myPieChart = new Chart(ctx3).Pie(graph3Generator("day"));
```

then I am adding (for each button) an event listener that destroys each canvas, and creates a new one with new information. Here is an example of the "week" button:

```
weekButton.addEventListener("click", function(){

    myChart.destroy();
    myChart = new Chart(ctx).Line(graph2Generator("Week"));

    myDoughnutChart.destroy();
    myDoughnutChart = new Chart(ctx2).Doughnut(graph2Generator("week"));

    myPieChart.destroy();
    myPieChart = new Chart(ctx3).Pie(graph3Generator("week"));


});
```

Comment: I find it weird that my mouse pointer is assumed to be somewhere about 100px lower and 50px more to the right than it actually is.

Comment: what browser are you using that allows you to see this issue, i am using chrome Version 42.0.2311.135 m, and do not see the described issue.

Comment: I have tested this on all browsers. That being, Chrome Version 42.0.2311.135 (64-bit), Safari Version 8.0.3 (10600.3.18) and, Firefox 37.0.2 . These I believe are the most up-to-date versions of each browser.

Comment: ChartJS has a `responsive` property which allows it to auto-resize. It defaults to false -- have you changed `Chart.defaults.global.responsive = true;`?

Comment: Not that I know of? I don't see anywhere in the fiddle that could of changed that. I updated my question to show essentially what is going on in the fiddle because its kind of large.

Comment: ChartJS does feel "overly entitled" to change the canvas size based on the chart type and data. You might also save the original canvas size and reset the `canvas.width=` and `canvas.height=` before requesting a new Chart with `.update` or `new Chart`.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the  element inside a wrapper and set its max-width to be 80% or as desired.

Turn off responsiveness.

Check out this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h42tv3xv/3/) and let me know whether you are still getting bloated chart on clicking re-renders.

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <canvas id="graph1" width="300" height="300"></canvas>

    <canvas id="graph2" width="250" height="250"></canvas>

    <canvas id="graph3" width="250" height="250"></canvas>  
</div>


.wrapper {
   max-width: 80%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same behaviour defining `padding` definition to my `canvas`. I removed `padding` and I have no resizing now.